# Lightbox Carousel did not show nav arrows on full screen

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel-2

I need help about showing Lightbox Carousel properly. After I created carousel and click one of the
image inside carousel it shows image but I can't navigate between other images because no navigation arrows there.

Here is my HTML and down below my scripts include Lightbox Carousel:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <!--Google Fonts-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Catamaran:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
     <!--Style-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
     <!--Lightbox Style-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/simple-lightbox.min.css">
    <title>Phono - Headphones of the Future</title>
</head>
<body id="home">
    <!-----------------------------------Navigation Area----------------------------------->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="logo">Phono</h1>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-----------------------------------Showbox------------------------------------------->
    <section class="showbox">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <h1>The Headphones of The Future</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos facilis modi reiciendis consequatur incidunt magni cupiditate voluptatum repellat iusto ipsam?</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
            </div>            
            <img src="./img/hphone3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </section>
   <!-----------------------------------Overlay------------------------------------------->
    <section class="part-a">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="part-a-inner">
                <h3>Loud & Clear</h3>
                <h2>People Aren't Hearing All The Music</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam dolor voluptates dignissimos vero reprehenderit dicta deleniti hic quae obcaecati nulla.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-----------------------------------Gallery------------------------------------------->
    <!--class:big Lightbox'tan gelen bir sınıf-->
    <section class="gallery">
        <div class="grid">
            <a href="./img/hphone7.jpg" class="big"><img src="./img/hphone7.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <a href="./img/phone8.jpg" class="big"><img src="./img/phone8.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <a href="./img/hphone6.jpg" class="big"><img src="./img/hphone6.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <a href="./img/hphone5.jpg" class="big"><img src="./img/hphone5.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <a href="./img/hphone4.jpg" class="big"><img src="./img/hphone4.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <a href="./img/hphone3.jpg" class="big"><img src="./img/hphone3.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3be9d2efad.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Jquery-->
    <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            const $gallery = $('.grid a').simpleLightbox();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my CSS :

```css
:root{
    --primary-color: #333;
    --secondary-color: #444;
    --overlay-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

*{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    line-height: 1.3;
}

a{
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.8rem 1.5rem;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
    transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: darkcyan;
    color: black;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--overlay-color);
}

.navbar{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding-top: 0.3rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

.navbar .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.navbar .logo {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.navbar .nav {
    justify-self: end;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navbar .nav a {
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.navbar .nav a:hover {
    color: #555;
}

.showbox {
    margin: 2rem 0;
}

.showbox .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 3rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.showbox h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}

.showbox p {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.part-a {
    position: relative;
    background: url('../img/hphone2.jpg') no-repeat bottom center/cover;
    height: 600px;
}

.part-a-inner {
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 860px;
    padding: 5rem 0;
}

.part-a-inner h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.part-a-inner h2 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.part-a-inner p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.gallery .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.gallery .grid a:first-child {
    grid-row: 1/3;
    grid-column: 1/3;
}

.gallery .grid a:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 3/5;
}

.gallery .grid img, .gallery .grid a {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the `z-index` property for the navigation buttons? Because it might be below `z-index` priority than the carousel images.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work too

Comment: Can you use another library? There are many simple but powerful carousels and image sliders.